# Sitecore Slack or Stack Exchange?

Tags: community

Is it still possible to join Sitecore Slack (http://sitecorechat.slack.com/)? How can I do this?

Can somebody please shed the light on what I should ask in Slack and what is better to ask in Stack Exchange and vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can find the Slack chat details here: https://sitecore.chat/**

You can sign up using this form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1bAVDgP5-FhFh8ohPchHtifq-rz7EBkuPojAzdEofJyo/viewform

**Slack** is more for chat and it does not have a history, so your questions and the answers will disappear.

Everything what is a concrete issue should be asked on **Stack Exchange** so the answer can be found forever.

Comment: Thanks, @Tamas!